# Points deleted in map do not delete in attribute table using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point, attribute-table, delete

In QGIS 3.22.13 I have deleted a number of points from a SHP file. They have gone from the map but still appear in the attribute table.

I have tried reloading the attribute table and saving closing and re-opening the layer. I have also updated to the current most stable version of QGIS.

When I select the deleted points in the attribute table and try to zoom to them I get an error message in the map which says

> 'Cannot zoom to selected feature: No extent could be determined'.

It is possible to manually select all points on the map, then invert the selection and delete the points that way. However I don't think this should be necessary. When a point is deleted in the map view it should be deleted in the attribute table. Can anyone help?

Comment: How did you delete them? Did you use the select tool, or did you delete the geometries using the vertex tool? The latter can cause issues.

Comment: Ahah, yes I used the vertex tool! Thanks Matt. Will use the select tool from now on.

Comment: The vertex tool is fine for deleting vertices from more complex geometries (lines, polygons). However, if you clear a feature's geometry with it (in your case deleting a single point from a point layer) then it causes the issue you faced. (The feature still exists but it has no geometry). Selecting the feature and deleting it removes the feature altogether from the layer.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Solved - Use select tool to delete points not the vertex tool.